# How can i find the end entry for a start entry in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I came across a table that has a similar structure to the below variable @t.
I want to find the end entry for each start entry but this gets difficult as entries can contain sub entries.

Any idea how i could find the EndEntryText for its cosponsoring StartEntryText using its position?

Visual Representation of the entries:

```
-- Start 1
--  Start 2
--  Stop 2
--  Start 3
--      Start 4
--          Start 5
--          Stop 5
--      Stop 4
--  Stop 3
-- Stop 1
```

Desired Output:

```
StartEntryText  EndEntryText
Start 1         Stop 1  
Start 2         Stop 2
Start 3         Stop 3
Start 4         Stop 4
Start 5         Stop 5
```

SQL:

```
-- Simplified Table Structure
DECLARE @t TABLE (EntryText varchar(16) NULL
    , EntryType varchar(16)
    , EntryIndex int NULL
)

-- Test Data
INSERT INTO @t(EntryText, EntryType, EntryIndex) 
SELECT d.EntryText
    , d.EntryType
    , d.EntryIndex
FROM 
(
    SELECT 'Start 1 ' AS EntryText, 1 AS EntryIndex, 'Open' AS EntryType
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Start 2' AS EntryText, 2 AS EntryIndex, 'Open' AS EntryType
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Stop 2' AS EntryText, 3 AS EntryIndex, 'Close' AS EntryType
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Start 3' AS EntryText, 4 AS EntryIndex, 'Open' AS EntryType
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Start 4' AS EntryText, 5 AS EntryIndex, 'Open' AS EntryType
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Start 5' AS EntryText, 6 AS EntryIndex, 'Open' AS EntryType
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Stop 5' AS EntryText, 7 AS EntryIndex, 'Close' AS EntryType
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Stop 4' AS EntryText, 8 AS EntryIndex, 'Close' AS EntryType
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Stop 3' AS EntryText, 9 AS EntryIndex, 'Close' AS EntryType
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Stop 1' AS EntryText, 10 AS EntryIndex, 'Close' AS EntryType
) d

-- TODO: Find EndEntryText
SELECT t.EntryText AS StartEntryText
    , NULL AS EndEntryText
FROM @t t
WHERE t.EntryType = 'Open'
```

Comment: Excellent first post! Voted up for being an almost perfect SQL question: A clear textual explanation of the problem, consumable sample data, readable desired results... The only thing missing to make this a perfect question would be if you showed us what you've already tried.
Kudos!

Comment: Is there any similarity in `EntryText` data for `open` and `close EntryType` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply's. No similarities in the EntryText, on my side it is a uniqueidentifier. I made it text in the example so it would be easier to explain.

Comment: So, then how do we know which `Close` corresponds to which `Open`?

Comment: [SWAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_wild-ass_guess): You want to "push" `'Open'` entries onto a stack and then "pop" and pair them as you encounter `'Close'` events (last-in, first-out or [LIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type))). Does `EntryIndex` provide the order in which to process the rows?

Comment: Correct, `EntryIndex` provide the order in which we process the rows. We know which close correspond to which open because of `EntryIndex`. For example in an object based language i would make a node class that takes the rows and for each `Open` create a child node and pass the rows collection and then for each `Close` yield to my parent node. If that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution but this should do what i need.

This basically works out the level of each entry by adding its ancestors together +1 for `OPEN` and -1 for `CLOSE`. Then gets the first `CLOSE` after each `OPEN` on the same level.

```
-- Workout Indent level for each entry in the hierarchy
SELECT t.EntryText
    , t.EntryIndex
    , t.EntryType
    , r.Indent
INTO #t
FROM @t t
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN s.EntryType = 'OPEN' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END)  
        + CASE WHEN t.EntryType = 'OPEN' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END AS Indent
    FROM @t s 
    WHERE s.EntryIndex <= t.EntryIndex
) r

-- Work out OPEN entry for CLOSE entry in the same level
SELECT tOpen.EntryText AS StartEntryText
    , t.EntryText AS EndEntryText
FROM #t t
OUTER APPLY   
(
    SELECT TOP(1) e.EntryText
        , e.EntryIndex
    FROM #t e
    WHERE e.EntryIndex < t.EntryIndex
        AND e.EntryType = 'OPEN'
        AND e.Indent = t.Indent
    ORDER BY e.EntryIndex DESC
) tOpen
WHERE t.EntryType = 'CLOSE'
ORDER BY tOpen.EntryIndex

DROP TABLE #t
```

Comment: Well, I wasn't getting there as I fiddled about. You could place the first query, less the `into` clause, in a common table expression ([CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)) and reference the CTE in the second query to eliminate the temporary table.